# Force.com One App license and Campaigns

Tags: force.com, campaign

I am using Force.com One app licence  which does not provide standard salesforce campaigns. Is there any way through which we can bring campaigns in this license as well using some external connector or app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, to access campaigns you need to have a "Salesforce" license and a "Marketing Feature License" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a Campaigns object, then using either Visual WorkFlow or Apex to mimic the Out of The Box options for Salesforce?

I think this would be your best shot.

Take care.

Regards,
Jose